Floating-point number in mips programming
I am working with mips programming on mars 4.5. This is the sample code:
.data
    half:   .float 0.1


.text
    l.s     $f12, half
    li  $v0, 2
    syscall

My purpose is print the number 0.1, and it worked when i use $f12 in the line
l.s    $f12, half

However, when i tried with the other register like $f1, $f13, ... the printed result is 0.0.
I am frustrated about how these registers work. Please help me explan it. Thank you so much for your replies

The syscall only prints $f12. It can not magically figure out you want something else. If you want to print another register you need to move it to $f12.

Documentation says the syscall with 2 in v0 prints the float in f12. That is all. It is not about how floating-point behaves or how the processor treats the registers. Somebody merely decided that syscall 2 would print the float value in f12, and they wrote the code for syscall 2 to do that, so that is what it does.
